# convert and import .osm.bz2 to postGis with osm2pgsql fails on Windows

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap

I am new in all this. I followed tutorial `http://www.spatialanalysis.ca/2011/using-openstreetmap-data-part1/` and did next:

-installed postGIS/postgreSql, PROJ4;

-saved link from cloudmade;

-create database gis;

and finally did  this in cmd 
`osm2pgsql -d gis -U postgres -P 5432 grad_beograd.osm.bz2`

and shows me error `Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Couldn't open style file '/usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style': No such file or d
irectory
Error occurred, cleaning up`

My OS is `WindowsXP`.

Asking for help.Thanks advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `-S` flag and point to the location of the `default.style` file - try the `osm2pqsql -h` command, which will tell you this:

```
 -S|--style       Location of the style file. Defaults to
                        default.style.
```

Make sure you actually have the file, that tutorial above doesn't really tell you where to get it, I had to do the HOTOSM install to get the `default.style` file and I just copied it into my folder with the OSM data.

Comment: I grabbed the file from the GitHub repo at https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style — seems to work

Answer (score 1):

From link `http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=loading_osm_postgis`

"If you don't see a default.style file in your package, download it from the above links. For the HOTOSM install, default.style is located in the Program Files/HOSTOSM/share folder. Copy the default.style file into the same folder as your massachusetts.osm.bz2 file.
Note: IF you plan to setup a mapping tile server with OSM data later, check out Dane Springmeyer's Mapnik tutorials: http://www.dbsgeo.com/."